# JavaScript for loop in reverse 5 times and get top 5 values only

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to run the loop in reverse and I wat to only 5 top values like
(16, 17, 18, 19, 20) but no mate how log is array

```
var arr = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
];

for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 5; i--) {
  console.log("=>", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `i > arr.length - 5`? You only want five values right?

Comment: modern browsers ... `for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) { console.log("=>", arr.get(-i));`

Comment: @evolutionxbox => you are right

Comment: Depending on what you have to do, you might also simply get the last five item of the array with `Array.prototype.slice()` and then manipulate that smaller array as needed.

Comment: `arr.slice(arr.length-5).reverse()` for `[20, 19, 18, 17, 16]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort total array by descending, then get the max 5 value and reverse them.

```
arr.sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5).reverse()
```

Comment: that's great man ( but I don't have enough reputation for vote ) but thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the array by calling `reverse` and after that use `slice` to get only 5 itmes, No need to rely on loop

```js
let arr = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
];

let result = arr.reverse().slice(0,5);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that's great man ( but I don't have enough reputation for vote ) but thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array from the end, reverse and iterate the items.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

for (const item of array.slice(-5).reverse()) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: that's great man ( but I don't have enough reputation for vote ) but thankyou